# Failed to resolve library from github

Tags: android

I am newbie in Android. I would like to add this library: [library](https://github.com/alshell7/VokaturiAndroid)

But i' ve got error : ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.alshell7:VokaturiAndroid:{1.03}
I am trying something like this: `implementation 'com.github.alshell7:VokaturiAndroid:{1.03}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gradle(Module App)  add this Dependency

`implementation 'com.github.alshell7:VokaturiAndroid:1.03'`

and then go to gradle ( Project ) and add this as following

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } //add this line of code 
    }
}
```

Don't forget to resynsc your project